# Need some urgent suggestion - Windows disks inaccessible after Ubuntu installation

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, partitioning, lvm

This is my first time using Ubuntu.
I wanted to dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04 on my Dell Inspiron 5521 laptop.

I was doing everything according to a tutorial I've seen.
At one point it asked me about what I should do. It had 4 options and the last option was **Something else**.
I clicked on the option called **LVM**.
After this the install was good, but to my horror now I cannot find Windows or any of my files anywhere. 
Please some urgent help is required.
These files are very urgently needed. Thank you.

These are the results of running `sudo fdisk -l` in the terminal:

[image]

Comment: What tutorial(s) did you follow? It's possible you formatted your disk (deleting Windows),

Comment: Edwin, I followed a tutorial on makeuseof.
I was having some problems using the "Something else" option and therefore clicked on "LVM".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "something else" mode it is up to you to make sure the partitions are preserved if you want them to be preserved - if you removed them, or created a new boot record it is likely that it will be quite difficult to recover the data. However, we need to first establish whether the Windows partition has been deleted or not.

Please stop all use of the machine, boot from the installation medium again and run `sudo fdisk -l` in the terminal. Then update your question with the command's answer. Alternatively you can run `gparted`, which is a graphical utility, make a screenshot and add it to your question.

**UPDATE:** From your screenshot it looks like you have a single HDD in your laptop (dell Inspiron, right?) and yes, you've deleted Windows partition(s) and overwrote them with Ubuntu. There is still a (slim) chance to recover some (not all) data from the Windows partition using tools like Photorec, but the first thing you need to do is to **STOP ALL USE OF THE MACHINE** - you're continuing to install programs on your hard drive and using it "as usual". Every byte written to the disk now reduces your chances of recovering your files.

Comment: Thankyou for replying..I couldn't add any images because I do not have 10 reputation points..here's the image for the same :- http://imageshack.us/f/17/2ls.png/

Also..the data was very important..I had 3 drives..I hope I get the data back.

Comment: @Akshay: The screenshot shows only one physical disk. Do you have only one or multiple physical disks in your machine? **By the way:** It is usually much better to add text output as text, not as a screenshot. Next time please copy the text and paste it into a *Code Sample* block on askubuntu.

Comment: @Akshay: I've updated my answer

Comment: @Sergey
What should I do now?What steps should I take ? Should I reinstall windows and then use the software you mentioned?

Comment: @Akshay: you should shut down your laptop NOW. Then you probably would take the HDD out, connect it to another machine and create a disk image. Then you put the HDD in a safe place and make sure not a byte is written to it. Then you would use Photorec to analyze the image, keeping the disk intact. You definitely should not install Windows or anything. There are also companies which specialize in data recovery, but that might be costly.

Comment: @Sergey
Thankyou, I'd do as suggested.